# Searching for a file in Nextcloud

Tags: webhooks, webdav, nextcloud

I need to check if I have a file in my Nextcloud before uploading another one (same name). I haven't found any way to do this using curl (the command I'm using to upload the new file). So, searching in [the client API of Nextcloud](https://docs.nextcloud.com/server/12/developer_manual/client_apis/index.html) I've found the webDAV search.

I've tried to use it before the upload to check if the file exists. This is what I've achieved:

```
    curl -u myUser:myPass 'https://nextcloud.customExample.com/remote.php/dav/' -X SEARCH -u myUser:myPass -H "content-Type: text/xml" --data '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<d:searchrequest xmlns:d="DAV:" xmlns:oc="http://owncloud.org/ns">
    <d:basicsearch>
        <d:select>
            <d:prop>
                <d:displayname/>
            </d:prop>
        </d:select>
        <d:from>
            <d:scope>
                <d:href>/files/myFolder/myFile.apk</d:href>
                <d:depth>infinity</d:depth>
            </d:scope>
        </d:from>
        <d:where>
            <d:like>
                <d:prop>
                    <d:getcontenttype/>
                </d:prop>
                <d:literal>text/%</d:literal>
            </d:like>
        </d:where>
        <d:orderby>
            <d:prop>
                <oc:size/>
            </d:prop>
            <d:ascending/>
        </d:orderby>
    </d:basicsearch>
</d:searchrequest>'
```

I'm getting this error when executing:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<d:error xmlns:d="DAV:" xmlns:s="http://sabredav.org/ns">
  <s:exception>Sabre\DAV\Exception\NotFound</s:exception>
  <s:message>Principal with name myFolder not found</s:message>
</d:error>
```

The folder myFolder is, as I see, in the root of my Nextcloud. I don’t know if I need something more to add before it (as I added “files”).

The user has permissions and using the curl command to upload the file with this same user is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all I've found an easier way to check if a file exists:

```
url='http://example.com/index.html'
if ( curl -o/dev/null -sfI "$url" ); then
  echo "URL exists"
else
  echo "URL does not exist"
fi
```

To that curl command you can add the `--user` parameter if you need authentication.

I've found it [here](https://gist.github.com/p120ph37/4f42a8f3ccc46bd8977e84acbd1b9251).